# Separate a line to columns using several spaces (>1) as a delimiter using C++ or linux

Tags: c++, linux, string, delimiter

I have several lines looking like this:

> 4539(random number of spaces)07235001(random number of spaces)Aach(random number of spaces)Trier Saarburg

I want to separate it to 4 columns using C++ or linux. The output I want will look like this:

> 4539|07235001|Aach|Trier Saasburg

So I want to treat several spaces as the delimiter but not the single one.

(random number of spaces thankfully is always > 1)

Lines do not always consist of 4 columns and the space problem is not always at the last column.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use a loop. i.e `while(next character is a space) { get next character }`

Comment: Thx for the comment. The real problem is the spaces that exist within a column. I dont want to separate Trier and Saasburg to two different columns cause Trier Saasburg is the name of the city (like New York etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use awk with regular expressions for this:

```
echo "4539     07235001      Aach    Trier Saarburg" | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "[ ]{2,}"  } { OFS = "|" };  {$1=$1; print $0 }'
```

`FS` variable is used to set the field separator for each record and may contain any regular expression. `OFS` is the output equivalent of the `FS` variable.

Answer (score 3):

You should read each field individually.  The last field can be read until a newline

```
character is received:  
std::string column1;
std::string column2;
std::string column3;
std::string column4;
while (input_file >> column1)
{
  input_file >> column2;
  input_file >> column3;
  getline(input_file, column4);
}
```

Another method is to read the entire line using `getline` and then fetch out the substring fields using `std::string::find` and `std::string::substr`.

Comment: Thx for the very useful comment but the problem is that i do not always have 4 columns and the city may not be the last column :(. This is my fault i should have made myself clearer.

Comment: I suggest talking to the person who wrote the output format.

Comment: Ok thank you! When i asked this i thought that the answer would be simple (identify more than one space fields and use this as the delimiter). Thx anyway :)